# Something Went wrong running 'pod install' in the 'ios' directory

Tags: ios, xcode, expo, simulator, yarn-v2

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/wG6w6.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wG6w6.png)

I'm trying to run xcode so my app runs in the simulator, it runs in the dev branch, but in the branch that i'm working on it doesn't. I deleted the expo files, ios files, some node modules, and cleaned all of my yarn.

Comment: try to run `pod install` directly  in the project/ios folder, the logs are not so clear